# Can't retrieve values from other page (Stored As Label)

Tags: php

I am new to PHP and I am trying to get information from a form to another page, but the data won't transfer over when I hit submit. What am I doing wrong? Should I be trying to use GET instead of POST? What is the best way to debug something like this?

The path to information.php is definitely correct.

```
<form action="information.php" method="post" type="post">
    <div class="row" style="padding-bottom: 20px;">
        <label name="tempID"><?php echo $number; ?></label>
        <button class="btn" name="submit" type="submit">More Details</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

**This file is in a different page (information.php)**

```
 if (isset($_POST["tempID"]))
 {
    $infoID = $_POST['tempID']; 
 }

 echo $infoID;
```

Comment: Remove `type="post"` plus your `<label name="tempID"><?php echo $number; ?></label>` won't work. It needs to be an input. I.e. `<input type="text" name="tempID">` or `<input type="text" name="tempID" value="<?php echo $number; ?>">` depending on what the desired result should be.

Comment: Let the feeding begin...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input type="hidden" name="tempID" value="<?php echo $number; ?>" />
```

Add this next to your original echo, post variables can't be stored in a label. Also remove the name value from the label

Answer (score 0):

You need a submit input instead of a button with the name submit.  Change the button's html to:

```
<input type='submit' value='More Details'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change Label in input

```
<form action="information.php" method="post">
    <div class="row" style="padding-bottom: 20px;">
        <input name="tempID" value="<?php echo htmlentities($number); ?>"/>
        <button class="btn" name="submit" type="submit">More Details</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

labels are only to display information. they are not submitted during form submission.

```
<form action="information.php" method="post" type="post">
    <div class="row" style="padding-bottom: 20px;">
        <label>Number:</label>
        <input name="tempID" value="<?php echo $number; ?>"/>
        <input class="btn" id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="More Detail" />
    </div>
</form>
```